# What does` if [ ${0#/} = ${0} ] ; then` mean?

Tags: shell, scripting

Saw a piece of code which has following condition:

```
if [ ${0#/} = ${0} ] ; then
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This test checks if script was run with relative or absolute path. It will evaluate to `true` if it was executed with relative path.

Variable:

```
${var#pattern}
```

is expanded to `${var}` with prefix `pattern` removed (in this case `/` will be removed from the beginning of the variable. This is called parameter expansion.

Variable:

```
${0}
```

contains the name, or the path, of the script.

Left side of the comparison:

```
${0#/}
```

will expand to path of the script with `/` prefix removed (if present)

Good description is [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Special_Parameters_and_Variables).